# Can't see created objects

Tags: excel, vba, object

I've created some simple classes in excel and I'm trying to create new objects from these classes. It works fine and let's me create them and I can also access the variables given to the object. I can't see the object in the local window though and I don't really understand why. Is it not created correctly because you are supposed to see your objects there I understand?

Here is the code for the class

```
Option Explicit


    'Teams

    Public Name As String
    Public Group As String 
    Public GF As Integer
    Public GA As Integer
    Public Points As Integer
    'Public Players(25) As String
    
    Private Sub class_initialize()
        Points = 5
    End Sub
```

and here is the code where I try to create an object

```
Sub TestTeams()    
    Dim Madagaskar As Object
    Set Madagaskar = New ETeam
    MsgBox (Madagaskar.Points)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Highly suggest you read up on properties, for example [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I have but it doesn't answer my question. Even if I use it the way they are describing it in that text it doesn't give me an object I can see

Comment: If you put `Stop` on the line after the MsgBox call and run `TestTeams`, you will see the object in the locals window.  It will only be there while `Madagaskar` is in scope and you're in break mode.

Comment: Oh right, thanks! Really new to vba, appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `Stop` on the line after the `MsgBox` call and run `TestTeams`, you will see the object in the locals window.

It will only be there while `Madagaskar` is in scope and you're in break mode.